# how to insert a row in jdbc

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc

ok so I am trying to add a record to my database but it isn't working (hence why I'm here asking a question)

no errors are being thrown... put a try catch in which executes fine so surely it should work?

when I run the code the server also starts and I can call methods from another project that are stored on the server project so I know that the server is working

```
public class RegisterUser {


    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

        Connection conn = null;
        Properties connectionProps = new Properties("admin", "adminadmin");

        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Social_Network");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            int nbUpdatedResult = stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO table (USERS) VALUES (INSERT INTO ADMINISTRATOR.USERS (USERID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, SEX, BIRTH, DEATH) \n"
                    + " VALUES ('1', 'salems24', 'Twisted1@', 'M', '2014-01-24', '2014-01-25')");
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

            System.out.println("Connected to database");

        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: That SQL insert statement looks really strange, invalid in fact. If you see "Connected to database", you have an error.

Comment: what is invalid about it? merely saying it's invalid doesn't help much

that isn't displayed

I used this
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: sorry I meant that 'connected to database' isn't displayed

Comment: The statement doesn't follow the standard SQL insert grammar. The second INSERT makes sense, however: `INSERT INTO ADMINISTRATOR.USERS (USERID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, SEX, BIRTH, DEATH)  VALUES ('1', 'salems24', 'Twisted1@', 'M', '2014-01-24', '2014-01-25')`. But you have two INSERT statements mixed together.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to have several erros, such as

1. properties, what properties is that?
2. SQL is wrong
3. next time provide the table structure
4. print stacktrace instead of exception message and provide it for us
5. do not print in the catch clause that you're connected when you're maybe not
6. how the method throws an exception that is caught?
7. do not use a string as primary key, this is not efficient

below there's a sample that works (although the table structure is probably too poor to be used outside an example like this)

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;


public class RegisterUser {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new RegisterUser().getConnection();
    }
    public Connection getConnection(){

        Connection conn = null;
        Properties props = new Properties();

        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:derby:derbyDB;create=true",props);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
//            stmt.executeUpdate("create table users (userid int not null primary key,username varchar(200), password varchar(200), sex varchar(200), birth date, death date)");
            int nbUpdatedResult = stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO USERS (USERID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, SEX, BIRTH, DEATH) VALUES (2, 'salems24', 'Twisted1@', 'M', '2014-01-24', '2014-01-25')");
            System.out.println(nbUpdatedResult);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok so now these warnings are displayed

WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Jan 26, 2014 2:45:40 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.

SEVERE:   SEC5054: Certificate has expired:

Comment: use your jdbc string, not mine.